# Is One Way Operation Contract faster?

Tags: c#, wcf

This is a really noob question. I wanted to know if the One Way Contract of the WCF is faster than its counterpart which return the result.For example Is

```
[OperationContract(IsOneWay=true)]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "/SendData/{data}", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedResponse,
RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
void SendData(string data)
```

faster than

```
[OperationContract(IsOneWay=false)]
[WebGet(UriTemplate="/SendData/{data}", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedResponse,
RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
bool SendData(string data)
```

the method SendData is like this with a lot of database code and locking

```
bool SendData(string data)
{
   check if data is valid
   if(data is valid)
   {
      lock(a database table)
      { 
         search duplicate data
         if(duplicate data found)
          {
            does not do anything (no-op)
          }
          else
          {
             save a data to the table
          }
          return true;
      }
   }
   else
   {
       return false;
   }
}
```

As you can see the method bool SendData(string data),have a lot of database and locking code.The main point of the question is should I change the Operation Contract to one way for faster result with the same code without changing anything.Or should my SendData method be like below to return the method faster

```
void SendData(string data)
{
   Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
               Do Task
            }
            );
}
```

Comment: I am using Android Volley as the JSON client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not faster per se, it's different.

A one-way call is one way. You send the message, that's it. It's fire-and-forget. If an exception is thrown in the service because for example the database could not be opened, you will never know. the call will return as soon as the message was delivered to the service. It will not wait until the service call completed.

If you want to wait until your service call is complete to make sure there were no errors, you will have to use the normal, non-one-way method.

Comment: Or he could implement a callback on the service. That way it acts as a fire-and-forget as far as the call goes, but when the service finishes its task or an exception is thrown, the user can still be informed.

Comment: @Nvoigt,do you mean in the method below

'code'
void SendData(string data)
{
 locking code
 database code
}

If I make SendData method One Way,the client does not have to wait for the duration that locking code and database code while if I make the SendData method not one way , it have to also wait duration of locking code and database code?

Comment: Notifying the user is not my main concern.

Comment: @LophtGhost basically, yes, the one-way method returns *immediately* after it has made sure your messages was transferred correctly to the service while the normal way would wait until the service successfully completes until it returns. One-way could be described as "fast, because you really don't care if it worked."